# store context in shared preference for facebook logout in Android

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

i develop a game project in which i have implemented facebook sdk for posting scores on the wall in facebook. But there is a problem for logout in facebook. I have to logout from facebook in settings page which is different page from where i have to login in facebook. In facebook SDK there is a function logout which requires the context from which i have logged in. I have to store context in shared preference for this. How can i do that?

Comment: You can pass any context to logout.

Comment: no i have tried different context but i cant logout from facebook

Answer (score 2):

I have done Same thing in my Code Like This... In your Activity Where you have Created object of Facebook make it public static like

```
public static Facebook mFacebook
```

and in activity where you want to logout From Facebook  use Following Function

```
private void LogoutFacebook()
{
    if(FacebookLoginActivity.mFacebook != null)
    {

        if (FacebookLoginActivity.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) 
        {
            AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new   AsyncFacebookRunner(FacebookLoginActivity.mFacebook);
            asyncRunner.logout(AdvanceSetting.this, new LogoutRequestListener());
        }
    }
}
```

also add this class where you want to Logout

```
 private class LogoutRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener 
    {
        public void onComplete(String response) 
        {

                    SessionEvents.onLogoutFinish();

        }
    }
```

Hope it may useful to you..

Comment: I am also facing same problem after making static still it wont work when phone is switch off and after again switch on then error occurs.